# Sinatra: put some of my helpers in separate folder

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app and I have some helpers and they have their folder (helpers) in which I have website_helpers.rb and so on. I want to move some of this helpers in their own folder inside the helpers folder: to have helpers/subhelpers, bacause the files I want to put in the subhelpers folder are different from the others and it makes sense to have a different folder for them.

I tried adding this to my `config.ru`

```
Dir.glob('./helpers/subhelpers/*.rb').each { |file| require file }
```

And then in the controller I have:

```
helpers MyHelperFromSubHelpers
```

but I get an error `uninitialized constant (NameError)`.

Any ideas how to fix this so that to have a clear structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH, it sounds like you're overdoing it, there's always Rails if you want to go in for a more Java like every-namespace-must-be-a-directory layout. Aside from that, usually, helpers in separate files are placed in the `Sinatra` namespace - see http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-request-context-with-sinatrahelpers

Personally, I put them in:

```
project-root/
  lib/
    sinatra/
      name-of-extension.rb
```

Mainly because if the extension is really useful, I'll end up wanting to use it in another project, and this is the standard layout for a Sinatra gem, which makes it easy to extract it into one and with barely any change in the calling code.

[Dir.glob will only return the file name and not the full path with each match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob), so you need to add the path:

```
Dir.glob('./helpers/subhelpers/*.rb').each do |file|
  require File.expand_path File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), "./helpers/subhelpers/", file)
end
```

will probably fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe I will leave it without subfolder, you're right it's a bit too much for a Sinatra app.